# The call is ambiguous between the following methods and properties - Linq and MoreLinq

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I have a line of code that has been written using MoreLinq here :

```cs
var maxPage = _pageState?.Value?.Pages?.MaxBy(p => p.Type.Grids["desktop"].ColCount)?.FirstOrDefault();
```

Because my solution is using both MoreLinq and Linq I am getting the following error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable.DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func<TSource, TKey>)' and 'System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func<TSource, TKey>)

I have tried adding the following static extension to my document:
`MoreLinq.Extensions.AppendExtension` but this errors out `FirstOrDefault()` at the end of the line  with the following error:

> 'MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'MyClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried also removing MoreLinq but I get the same does not contain a defition for FirstOrDefault Error.

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you still need the `using` directive for `MoreLinq` in the same source file, or was that the only use of MoreLinq in that file? I don't understand what you mean about adding a static extension to your document - what document? Do you mean source file? Is this related to the first error or is it separate? At the moment your question is quite unclear.

Comment: @JonSkeet Its the only use of MoreLinq in the file

Comment: So get rid of `using MoreLinq;` and it should be fine. It'll just use `Enumerable.MaxBy`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I end up getting the second error mentioned above about firstordefault

Comment: Please rewrite your question, as it's *very* unclear at the moment that that's how you got to the second problem, and also what you mean in your attempt to fix the second problem. A [mcve] would make everything much clearer.

Comment: Also note that your question talks about an error with `DistinctBy` despite you using `MaxBy` rather than `DistinctBy`. Again, a [mcve] would make everything much clearer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MaxBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-7.0) and [`DistinctBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-7.0) methods were introduced in .NET 6 which will result in the aforementioned problem if you are using `MoreLinq`. If you don't need any `MoreLinq` methods just remove it or replace with `using System.Linq;` (if you are not using the global/implicit usings).

If you still need both you can use the trick with splitting imports on before and after namespace (though it can be a bit esoteric):

```cs
// ... common imports
using MoreLinq.Extensions;

namespace YourNameSpace;
{
    using System.Linq; // default LINQ methods will be preferred

    // ... code
}
```

Or use static imports for only needed methods (see [@github](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/527)):

```cs
using static MoreLinq.Extensions.BatchExtension; // import classes holding needed extensions
```